# What is the error in this Floyd-Warshall implementation?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

Here is the problem link: http://codeforces.com/contest/295/problem/B

Greg has a weighed directed graph, consisting of n vertices. In this graph any pair of distinct vertices has an edge between them in both directions. Greg loves playing with the graph and now he has invented a new game:

The game consists of n steps.
On the i-th step Greg removes vertex number xi from the graph. As Greg removes a vertex, he also removes all the edges that go in and out of this vertex.
Before executing each step, Greg wants to know the sum of lengths of the shortest paths between all pairs of the remaining vertices. The shortest path can go through any remaining vertex.
Help Greg, print the value of the required sum before each step.

Input:

The first line contains integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 500) — the number of vertices in the graph.

Next n lines contain n integers each — the graph adjacency matrix: the j-th number in the i-th line aij (1 ≤ aij ≤ 105, aii = 0) represents the weight of the edge that goes from vertex i to vertex j.

The next line contains n distinct integers: x1, x2, ..., xn (1 ≤ xi ≤ n) — the vertices that Greg deletes.

Output:

Print n integers — the i-th number equals the required sum before the i-th step.

So, basically my approach was to run Floyd-Warshall algorithm before deleting any vertex, and for deletion, I would simply set the value of the vertex which to be deleted as `INT_MAX` in the adjacency matrix in both rows and columns.

Basically, this loop is in `main`

```
    for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
    {
        func();
        int val = arr[h];   // arr contains the vertices to be deleted
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            dist[val][i] = INT_MAX;
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            dist[i][val] = INT_MAX;
    }
```

This is my implementation of Flloyd Warshall algorithm:

```
void func () 
{
    //int i,j,k;
    ans = 0;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
        {
            if (i == j)
                val[i][j][0] = 0;
            else if (dist[i][j] != 0)
                val[i][j][0] = dist[i][j];
            else
                val[i][j][0] = INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
                val[i][j][k] = min(val[i][j][k-1],val[i][k][k-1]+val[k][j][k-1]);   
    //int ans = 0;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            ans = ans + val[i][j][n];
    cout<<ans<<"\t";
}
```

Here, `val` is the 3-D matrix that I have made global, and `arr` contains the vertices that are to be deleted. However, when I run this logic, it gives right answer only initially, that is when no vertex has been deleted. But after that, it gives a wrong value. I don't understand why? Is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Make a very small graph, remove a vertex and **debug** your code. Finding your own mistake is a lot better than us doing it for you (assuming we could find it).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that looks strange is that at the end you are meant to calculate the sum of all pairs of *remaining* vertices, but your loop is simply over all vertices:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
        ans = ans + val[i][j][n];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way and will get TLE ....
Follow this way

U should bear in mind the good understanding of floyd warshall algorithm .

First make yourself clear then come to this point , in this algorithm in any order u can design your intermediate elements (k) . So here are n steps that means n nodes will be deleted with given order …… That means in this given order u can design your intermediate elements .. say given deleted order set is [ 1 , 2 , 3 ] ……………..

Now that means when 1 vertex will be deleted then the total sum of the every pairs of shortest path . Then when 2 is also deleted then and so on………

Now think this like way that when only think all vertex deleted without 3 ,here using k(3) u can make sum of when only 3 is remaining , now make the value of k is (2 ) that means only 2 and 3 is remaining other are deleted now make sum ……..So if u reverse this answer that when 1 2 3 is remaining then sum ( no vertex deleted ) , then 1 delted

that means oonly 2 , 3 is remaining other deleted make sum of them ……….

So , I think this should be clear if u have good idea regarding floyd warshall algorithm

My neat and clean solution here based upon above idea

https://github.com/joy-mollick/Problem-Solving-Solutions/blob/master/Codeforces-B%20-%20Greg%20and%20Graph.cpp